# C++ WinAPI save and open dialogues

Tags: c++, winapi, load, save

How do I implement a save and load dialogue box into my current project? I only need to know how change the basics, like the filename mask and default path.

Any help appreciated, or even a link to a helpful website.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[TheForger's WinAPI tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/app_two.html) is the best IMHO and the part I linked also answers your question.

In WinAPI, the save and open dialogs are created by the functions `GetSaveFileName()` and `GetOpenFileName()`. The parameters of the dialog, such as the file name filter is stored in an `OPENFILENAME` struct.

- [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [GetSaveFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646928%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [OPENFILENAME struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646839%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)